# Node.js how to use a alert message in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I work in Node.js and I want that after the user entered the wrong username and password when logging in on the site, he was not given just a white screen (and in console. log ("the request failed")) and since the photo that I will attach below. To send a message from the top.

Like alert() I want. But for some reason it doesn't work in node.js

[image]

UPD: I installed the alert package. Alert works now, but window.alert doesn't

Answer (score 0):

window.alert() will not work in Node because Node JS is used to make a backend of any project. It helps in creating backend requests like connecting with a DB. It does not have any control over the broswer.  Window.alert() is a browser call.